# Unexpected behavior C++ standard output

Tags: c++, stdout

https://ideone.com/P4BOmY

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    int n,m,k;
    scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&m,&k);
    if(k>n || k>m)
    {
         printf ("0");
         return 0 ;  
    } 
    printf("1");
    return 0;
}
```

What is going on, why stdout empty on ideone ?

Comment: Adding "\n" seems to fix it. `fflush` does too, but only on the second and subsequent runs. *shrug* Quirk of ideone I suppose.

Comment: Okay, this is a pet peeve of mine. `return 0;}` "Nylon-wrapped" code with braces is a pain to read. Indentation doesn't designate blocks in C++, the brackets do. So do place them in a visually appropriate place. By that I mean, match them to the scope beginning, and not to the end of some line.

Answer (score 1):

It's a buffering issue. Using

```
printf("0\n");
```

and

```
printf("1\n");
```

fixes the problem. See it working at https://ideone.com/EUR5Dv.